# How can I create a slot in an S4 class for robust linear models?

Tags: r, class, r-s4

I would like to create an S4 class that has slots which can hold robust linear models.

Robust linear models are a type of linear model from the `MASS` package. They carry all of the information a linear model has and a bit more.

```
library(MASS)
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
mylm <- lm(x~y)
myrlm <- rlm(x~y)
```

Here is my class:

```
.MyClass <- setClass("MyClass", list(a="lm", id="numeric"))
```

Even though `.MyClass(a=mylm, id=1)` produces the expected object, initializing an object with an `rlm` fails:

```
> .MyClass(a=myrlm, id=1)
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “MyClass” object: 1: invalid object for slot "a" in class "MyClass": got class "rlm", should be or extend class "lm"
invalid class “MyClass” object: 2: invalid object for slot "a" in class "MyClass": got class "lm", should be or extend class "lm"
```

I would have thought that since `is(myrlm, "lm")` returns `TRUE` there wouldn't be an issue and the object could fit in the slot. Also, since it is telling me I created an invalid object twice, why is the second one saying that `lm` is not itself? Is it because `lm` is a virtual class?

I've tried setting `a="list"` in the representation (since `lm` and `rlm` are both lists), but that produces a similar error. Does the slot need a different class type? I've also tried setting `a="rlm"`, but `rlm` is not defined class.

Comment: great question.  I suspect you're descending into a hell of S3/S4 incompatibilities, but I hope (for your sake) that you're not. You might (???) try creating an S4 class that encompasses/wraps the S3 "rlm" class ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the fact that `rlm` objects has two `S3` classes. I suggest, as a work-around, to define a constructor and change the class of the slots before creating the object. Something along these lines:

```
   library(MASS)
   x <- 1:5
   y <- 1:5
   mylm <- lm(x~y)
   myrlm <- rlm(x~y)
   .MyClass <- setClass("MyClass", list(a="lm", id="numeric"))
   MyClass<-function(a,id) {
     if (!is(a,"lm")) stop("error")
     class(a)<-"lm"
     new("MyClass",a=a,id=id)
   }
   MyClass(myrlm,1)
```

Comment: Nice! I guess since `lm` is a virtual class, there isn't really any object validation. Looks like it works for any list-like object and virtual class.